# How can we insert an xml file directly into a mysql table in java?

Tags: java, mysql

How can we insert an xml file directly into  a mysql table in java?

Comment: Short answer -**no** , long answer- **you cannot**.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ isn't it just a string?

Comment: @JasonSperske He don't want to put the String, He wan't to put whole file. Possible solution is only storing the data ,i.e xml content as a String or maintaining/storing that file on server

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt your xml to specific mysql format using xslt and after it you can use LOAD_XML statement.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Comment: XSLT is one way to do it; any means of matching the file structure to the example given in the mysql reference you gave will work.  For example, one might use a perl script to convert existing XML to use the format shown.

Answer (score 0):

"xml file directly into a `mysql`" --> I am not clear what does it mean.But, you can insert any files to database as `Binary Steam or byte array` in java.
Please check below example...

EXAMPLE

```
public class InsertXML {
    private static final String INSERT_SQL =  "INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT(FILENAME, MIMETYPE, CONTENT) values(?, ?, ?)";

    public void insert(File xmlFile) {
         PreparedStatement ps = null;
         Connection con = null;
         try {
             ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
             ps.setString(1, xmlFile.getName());
             ps.setString(2, getMimeType(xmlFile));
             ps.setBinaryStream(3, new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
             ps.executeUpdate();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             // CLOSE ps and con;
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // CLOSE ps and con;
         } finally {
             // CLOSE ps and con;
         }
     }

     public String getMimeType(File xmlFile) {
         String mimeType = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
            mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mimeType;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         InsertXML insertXML = new InsertXML();
         insertXML.insert(new File("D:\test.xml"));
     }
}
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE ATTACHMENT (
  FILENAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  MIMETYPE VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  CONTENT LONGBLOB NOT NULL
)
```